# Recebendo código 200 quando deveria ser 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, http-status

Criei uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC 5 adicionando os seguintes trechos de código:

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Erro/Erro404"/>
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode != 404) //Condição para ignorar erros 404.
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();
            Logger.Registrar(ex.ToString()); //Método que registra o erro em um arquivo de log.
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/Erro/Desconhecido");
        }
    }
```

Como eu já configurei uma action para erros 404, quero que estes passem direto pelo `Application_Error`, levando assim o usuário para `~/Erro/Erro404`.

O problema: os erros 404 sempre entram no `if` em `Application_Error`, pois o servidor retorna um status code 200 (OK), quando deveria ser 404 (Not Found).

Alguém sabe dizer onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1):

Tente inverter a sequência de verificação:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Exception Ex = Server.GetLastError();
   if (Ex != null)
   {
      HttpException httpEx = Ex as HttpException;
      if (httpEx != null && httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404)
      {
         ... tratamento da 404 ...
      } else {
         Response.Clear();
         Logger.Registrar(ex.ToString());
         Server.ClearError();
         Response.Redirect("~/Erro/Desconhecido");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Botei o `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` dentro de `Application_Error()` e o `Response.StatusCode = 404;` no início da view `~/Erro/Erro404`. A view agora retorna 404, mas só se for acessada diretamente. O resto não mudou nada. Era assim que eu devia fazer?

Comment: Quando acessa um caminho inválido o que acontece?

Comment: é recebido a view com código 200 e o parâmetro `?aspxerror=/endereco-errado-aqui` ao final do endereço.

Comment: IIS 8.0. É no Azure Websites.

Comment: @tkpb atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Para recuperar o erro use assim no seu `Application_Error`

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    var code = (error is HttpException) ? (error as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;

    if (code == 404)
    {
        //codificação
    }

}
```

*Referências:*

- [How to: Handle Application-Level Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Using Application_Error in ASP.NET MVC’s global.asax to Handle Errors](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/using-application_error-in-asp-net-mvcs-global-asax-to-handle-errors/)
- [HttpServerUtility.GetLastError Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx)